# How to make live template in Visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, macros, live-templates

How to make live template in Visual studio 2010, I don't know is it really live template or macro, but what I wan't to do is when I'm write code and when I type let's say -> in, and press space, that program automatically insert code that look like this -> #include <>.
In c++ builder for that purpose we use xml file who is automatically insert text when we call it, in this case we will write it name (in), and reaction on it will be #include <>.

So is there someone who can tell me some advice, or good link to solve that mystery :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commercial (not free) addin [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) may be worth looking at.  It has a feature called [VA Snippets](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/vasnippets.asp) that does what you describe.